# cannot pass json object to mvc action

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am trying to call an mvc 3 action method with jquery ajax. please let me note that I am generating a partial view in ajax, and in the generated partial view, I am calling ajax again (it is something like nested ajax calls). here is my code:

the partial view:

```
@model MYWeb.UI.Models.ClientDetailsViewModel
```

The javascript in the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#savedetails@(i)").click(function () {

        var clientNumber = $('#ClientNumber@(i)').val();
        var clientName = $('#ClientName@(i)').val();

        var client =
{
    ClientNumber: clientNumber,
    ClientName: clientName
};

alert(JSON.stringify(client));

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/ClientUpdate',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(client),
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#loader@(i)_details").fadeIn('fast');
            },
            complete: function () {
                $("#loader@(i)_details").fadeOut('fast');
            },
            success: function () {
                $("#loader@(i)_details").fadeOut('fast');
                if ($("#ModelFirstError").val())
                    showModelMessageError;
                else
                    showUpdateMessageSuccess();
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#loader@(i)_details").fadeOut('fast');
                showUpdateMessageError();
            },
            async: true,
            processData: false
        });
    });
});
```

the Model object:

```
public class ClientDetailsViewModel
{
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(adm), Name = "ClientNumber")]
    public int ClientNumber { get; set; }


    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredClientName", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(adm))]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(adm), Name = "ClientName")]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    more fields...
}
```

the action method:

```
[Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ClientUpdate(ClientDetailsViewModel client)
        {}
```

this attempt to update always returns the ajax error. what am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I noticed that when I remove the parameter to the action method, it does get called.
But how can I pass the model this way?

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ClientUpdate()
    {}
```

Comment: yes the user is authenticated.

Comment: What is your `i` in `#loader@(i)_details` here? Are `#ClientNumber@(i)` and `#ClientName@(i)` controls exist in the page? what is the JSON sent to server (you can see that through browser developer tool)? Does this call hit the server?

Comment: @Paritosh the call reaches the ajax lines, but does not hit the server. I checked it and clientNumber and clientName are populated correctly.

Comment: I get an error 500 from the console, file not found

Comment: @Vobs from where did you passed the i and whats its value

Comment: i is a variable which holds the tab index I am in. it is always 2 for the discussion sake...